Why are duplicate words being highlighted?
I recently upgraded to version 14.1.
When I am editing text in a notebook and I click on a word, all occurrences of that word get highlighted. I would like to turn off this behavior. Is this a Mathematica option or an option of my operating system (MacOS Ventura 13.6.9)?
I've looked in the option inspector and don't see an appropriate option that controls this behavior.

I believe this is a new-in-14.1 feature, go to this blog post and search "new syntax coloring".  If you search the options inspector for CodeAssistOptions you might find a setting that allows to turn it off.
